# how can i export cytoscape graph to a format that i can edit with microsoft office

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, graphml

I use cytoscape to generate graph from text input.
and now I export this graph to png file.

the probleme is without my app i can't edit this graph.

and I want a way to use this lib to have data in order to obtain data usable with libre office or microsoft office